# Bean placeholder?

Tags: java, spring

Spring has [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://goo.gl/BnnvE). Is there something similar that uses beans instead of property files?

Say I have

```
<bean id="baseUrl" class="java.lang.String">
  <constructor-arg value="http://example.com" />
</bean>

<bean id="destUrl" class="java.lang.String">
  <constructor-arg value="${baseUrl}/dest" />
</bean>
```

Then I'd like the value of `destUrl` to be "http://example.com/dest".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Spring 3.0 you can use [SpEL expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html):

```
<bean id="destUrl" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="#{baseUrl}/dest" />
</bean>
```